# F10 and normal RUN gives different output

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that gives different outputs depending on if I debug with F10 or simply run the program. Even with F5 from one point to another returns the "weird" output. But if I debug it step by step it gives the correct output.

The project contains some commands that I send to a function generator and, depending on what returns, it shows one picture or another.

I thought that the problem could be that the function generator would need more time to send and receive the data, but I made it 10x longer and the problem doesn't change.

What can cause this problem? Maybe something in the cache or it's definitely my code's problem?

The code where the problem happens:

```
result = ""
    Do Until result <> ""
        SendToMachine("SOURCE2:APPL" & vbLf, result)
        If result = "" Then GoTo finish
        Select Case result
            Case ....
        End Select
finish:
    Loop
```

Normally the first loop, `result` gives nothing because it always fails, but the second time if i do it with F10 it works perfectly. It returns the value that is supposed to return and after that the code works perfectly.
When i dont use F10 it shows some rare values.
Maybe the problem is using `Goto`?.

Comment: It does sound like a timing problem. Have you tried adding a debug point somewhere, then running the program with F5, then step through with F11, and seeing where the latest line of code at which you can place the debug point is without the weird behaviour? The next piece of code should be where the problem is - and perhaps you could then [edit] your question to show us that code.

Comment: You can also try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that assignment to `result` is not atomic, and so you're getting a partial update to it?  Depending on what you're doing, you might need a `SyncLock` or other synchronization mechanism to guarantee that you can't see it when it's only partially written.